# Как переместить объект вдоль пути SVG с помощью клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, html5, svg, анимация, canvas

У меня есть `path` SVG, показанный на рисунке ниже. Мне нужно переместить красный круг  с помощью клавиатуры. Если наступает поворот, то нужно использовать левую или правую кнопку со стрелкой, в зависимости от направления поворота. Как я могу добиться этого с помощью JavaScript?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to move an object in svg path using keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52801643/7394871) от участника  [@byteC0de](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5137527/bytec0de).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/52801643/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это конечно содержит существенные ограничения - зато лаконично.

```js
window.focus();
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  let direction = e.keyCode - 38;
  if (Math.abs(direction) !== 1) return;
  let offset = parseFloat(player.getAttribute('startOffset'));
  offset = (offset + direction + 98)%98;
  player.setAttribute('startOffset', offset + '%');
})
```

```html
<svg viewbox=0,0,300,200 width=90vw height=90vh>
    <path id="route" stroke="red" fill="none" d="M75,120L100,0l100,30q110,100,10,150z"/>
    <text><textPath xlink:href="#route" id="player" startOffset="0%"></textPath></text>  
</svg>
```

Comment: замечательно, можно подробней об ограничениях, которые упомянул и не могу понять, как реализовано движение вперед - назад, ведь коды клавиш не указаны конкретно. То есть как расшифровать условие срабатывания только двух стрелок - `offset = (offset + e.keyCode - 38 + 98)%98;`

Comment: @Alexandr_TT =) это просто, коды влево и вправо 37 и 39, если из них вычесть 38 получится +-1, т.е. направление изменения offset, ограничения в том что не любой символ можно поставить, а только символ шрифта, ну и остальные клавиши н

Answer (score 4):

Я  думаю, что вы не сможете использовать стрелку влево или вправо, чтобы переместить красную точку влево, вправо так, как вы собираетесь. На самом деле я не понимаю логику.

Однако вы можете переместить точку вперед или назад, используя стрелки вправо и влево.

В моем коде начальное значение равно `0`, а красная точка находится в начале пути. Значение увеличивается или уменьшается в зависимости от используемой клавиши со стрелкой.

Шаг составляет 1/100 длины пути.

```
if(e.keyCode == 37){value ++;}
else if(e.keyCode == 39){value --;}
```

Если значение меньше `0` или больше `100`, я сбрасываю значение:

```
if(value > 100){value %= 100;}
if(value < 0){value += 100}
```

Я получаю позицию на пути, используя метод `getPointAtLength()`. Надеюсь это то что,  нужно.

`let position = circuit.getPointAtLength(totalLength*value/100);`

```js
window.focus()
let totalLength = circuit.getTotalLength();


let value = 0;

window.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
  
  if(e.keyCode == 37){value ++;}
  else if(e.keyCode == 39){value --;}
  
  if(value > 100){value %= 100;}
  if(value < 0){value += 100}
  
  let position = circuit.getPointAtLength(totalLength*value/100);
   updateElement({cx:position.x, cy:position.y}, thumb)
  
})



function updateElement(o, element) {
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      element.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  return element;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid #d9d9d9; max-width:100vh}


#circuit{
  stroke:black;
  fill:none;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  fill-opacity:.85
}

circle{fill:red}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="30 30 300 300">

    <path id="circuit" d="M187.476,214.443c-2.566,11.574-4.541,22.658-7.542,33.456
        c-3.558,12.8-7.14,25.713-12.242,37.938c-10.223,24.495-41.321,29.239-58.824,9.548c-9.592-10.792-11.295-26.9-3.539-40.556
        c11.233-19.778,25.391-37.46,40.447-54.438c1.07-1.207,2.116-2.436,3.893-4.484c-7.212,0.9-13.349,1.988-19.529,2.374
        c-16.283,1.018-32.578,2.21-48.881,2.437c-18.686,0.261-32.846-10.154-37.071-26.055c-6.762-25.449,15.666-48.973,41.418-43.338
        c23.645,5.175,46.447,12.901,68.424,23.051c1.033,0.478,2.083,0.918,3.933,1.731c-0.83-1.947-1.341-3.225-1.911-4.475
        c-9.896-21.701-18.159-43.986-23.192-67.337c-4.587-21.28,8.933-40.56,29.946-43.257c20.134-2.585,38.124,12.991,39.091,34.294
        c1.029,22.682-0.049,45.292-3.58,67.755c-0.17,1.079-0.152,2.188-0.246,3.659c8.05-6.831,15.471-13.737,23.52-19.811
        c11.147-8.412,22.398-16.795,34.27-24.113c18.35-11.312,40.821-4.481,50.028,14.385c9.091,18.628,0.131,40.586-20.065,48.198
        c-11.034,4.158-22.248,7.944-33.594,11.143c-11.321,3.191-22.908,5.438-34.866,8.212c1.189,0.81,2.19,1.504,3.205,2.18
        c18.402,12.261,37.157,24.032,55.101,36.932c14.769,10.616,18.619,29.317,10.675,44.578c-7.537,14.477-25.151,22.136-40.767,17.583
        c-7.583-2.212-14.022-6.469-18.523-12.919c-12.463-17.86-24.638-35.924-36.898-53.925
        C189.24,217.849,188.547,216.357,187.476,214.443z"/>

  
  <circle id="thumb" cx="187.476" cy="214.443" r="5" fill="black" />
  
 
</svg>
```

Пожалуйста, не забудьте кликнуть в окне сниппета, перед использованием стрелок.

### Update

***Примечание переводчика***

По комментарию **@Stranger in the Q** добавил `window.focus()`и не нужно стало кликать в окне сниппета

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802136/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Comment: `window.focus()`

Comment: С этим не нужен будет клик, по крайней мере в хроме - пашет